# derivative and integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

I have this function $$  h(t,x)=\int_0^{b} f(t,s)g(s,x) ds $$

What is $\frac{d}{dt} h(t,x)$ equal to ?

is it $\displaystyle[f(t,b) g(b,x)-f(t,0)g(0,x)] \int_0^b (\frac{d}{dt} f(t,s))g(s,x) ds$

where:

$f(t,s)=\begin{cases} \exp(-s)(exp(t)-exp(-t)),\, t<s\\ \exp(-t)(exp(s)-\exp(-s)),s<t\end{cases}$

and

$g(s,x)=\begin{cases} \exp(-2x)(exp(2s)-exp(-2s)),\, s<x\\ \exp(-2x)(exp(2x)-\exp(-2x)),x<s\end{cases}$

Comment: is $\int_{0}^b |f(t,s)g(s,x)| <\infty$? If so you can say it is $\int_0^b \frac{d}{dt}f(t,s)g(s,x)ds$

Comment: it is defined with exponential I don't think so

Comment: can you tell us what it is

Comment: $f(t,s)=\begin{cases} \exp(-s)(exp(t)-exp(-t)),\, t<s\\ \exp(-t)(exp(s)-\exp(-s)),s<t\end{cases}$.

Comment: $g(s,x)=\begin{cases} \exp(-2x)(exp(2s)-exp(-2s)),\, s<x\\ \exp(-2x)(exp(2x)-\exp(-2x)),x<s\end{cases}$

Comment: You can say:

$\int_0^b f(t,s)g(s,x)ds = \int_0^t f(t,s)g(s,x)ds + \int_t^{b}f(t,s)g(s,x)ds$ take the $exp(t)-exp(-t)$ and $exp(-t)$ terms out of the integral and use Liebniz integral rule.

Comment: so what I write I my question

Comment: Where is this formula from?  It appears to be overly complicated for this case since the functions are continuous and the integral doesn’t depend on $t$.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^b f(t,s)g(s,x)ds = \int_0^t f(t,s)g(s,x)ds + \int_t^{b}f(t,s)g(s,x)ds$

So $\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^b f(t,s)g(s,x)ds = \frac{d}{dt}[e^{-t}\int_0^t (e^s -e^{-s})g(s,x)ds]+\frac{d}{dt}[(e^t - e^{-t})\int_t^{b}e^{-s}g(s,x)ds] =  -e^{-t}\int_0^t (e^s - e^{-s})g(s,x)ds  +e^{-t}(e^t-e^{-t})g(t,x)+ (e^t + e^{-t})\int_t^b e^{-s}g(s,x)ds-(e^{t}-e^{-t})e^{-t}g(t,x)  = \int_0^t f_t(t,s)g(s,x)ds$

Using the product rule